# Dynamic program updating, runtime compilation, and class loaders

Tags: java, classloader, runtime-compilation

I have an application that needs the ability to update parts of itself (one class at a time) without stopping and restarting. With the JavaCompiler API, it is straightforward to generate modified class source code, recompile, load, and instantiate a class. I can do this all in memory (no files read from disk or net).

The application will never instantiate more than one object of such a class. There will only be two or three references to that object. When the modified class is loaded and instantiated, all those references will be changed to the new object. I can also probably guarantee that no method in the affected class is running in another thread while loading the modified class.

My question is this: will my class loader have problems loading a modified class with the same name as a class it previously loaded?

If I do not explicitly implement a cache of loaded classes in the class loader, would that avoid problems? Or could delegation to a parent class loader still cause a problem?

I hope to use a single instance of my class loader, but if necessary, I could instantiate a new one each time I update a class.

Note: I looked at OSGI and it seems to be quite a bit more than I need.

Comment: I have something very similar to this. You will have to specify to use JDK in order to compile it, or else you will get errors with the JavaCompiler returning null.

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful example on this at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

We do quite a bit of dynamic class reloading ourselves (using Groovy for compilations).  Note if you've got class dependencies then you may need recompile these dependencies on reload.  In dev stacks we keep a track of these dependencies and then recompile whenever dependencies become stale.  In production stacks we opted for a non-reloading ClassLoader and create a new ClassLoader when ever anything changes.  So you can do it either way.

BTW - you might find the GroovyScriptEngine at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/1.8.5/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java#GroovyScriptEngine very interesting if you want to dig around how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it *should* work: when you load the new class, it will replace the class name in the appropriate tables, and the memory should be GC'd.  That said, I'd give it a strenuous test with a real short program that compiles a nontrivial class and replaces it, say 10,000 times.